# org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: unix protocol is not supported

Tags: jenkins, docker

My jenkins is running using official jenkins image from docker hub.
When trying to connect to docker cloud using url: unix:///var/run/docker.sock, I got error "org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: unix protocol is not supported".

If i am trying same thing on jenkins which is not running as docker container than its working fine without any error.

Answer (score 1):

When you run jenkins in a docker container then, these are few things you should check -

- start the container:

  `run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name
     jenkins-master -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v
     $(which docker):$(which docker) jenkins-master-img:latest`
- Permission of `/var/run/docker.sock` set correctly
- Check the docker plugin version installed, with jenkins version 2.32.2 docker plugin version 0.16.2 throws exception `unix protocol is not supported` however, I tested with jenkins version 2.32.2, and docker plugin version 0.16.1 it works just fine.

Comment: I got following error, how to set permission of docker.sock

org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketException: Permission denied (socket: /run/docker.sock)
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketException: Permission denied (socket: /run/docker.sock)

Comment: Either you can change the permission of `chmod 0666 /var/run/docker.sock` on docker host (not recommended) or  it would be a good practice to add jenkins user into docker group so that you will not have to set rw for others.

Comment: `add jenkins user into docker group` this should be done in jenkins container or docker host? How can i do it?

Comment: In my system dockerd is running as user `root` and group `docker` so inside jenkins docker container, pls create `docker` group with same id as in host for group `docker` and then add jenkins user in container to docker group.

Comment: you can read this on how to do it - `http://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo`

Comment: I am running docker for mac on MacOSX, how can i know my docker is running as which user and group ?